# Show that matrix $B$ is an inverse from the left but not from the right

Tags: matrices, algebra-precalculus

We are given two non square matrices where $B$ is a $3 \times 2$ and $A$ is a $2 \times 3$. It says show that $B$ is an inverse from the left but not from the right. So I thought that all I had to do was take $BA$ and show that I get the identity matrix. Then do the same thing and show that $AB$ does not yield the Identity matrix but when multiplying $BA$ I definitely did not get the identity matrix. Am I approaching this problem incorrectly?

$$B=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 1\\
    0 & 2\\
    -1 & 1\\
    \end{bmatrix};\quad
 A =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 2 \\
    \end{bmatrix}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely not possible for $BA$ to yield the identity, as $\text{rank}(BA) \leq \text{rank}(B) \leq 2$ as it has two columns. But $BA$ is $3 \times 3$, so it cannot be full rank, and in particular, cannot be the identity. Perhaps you mixed up the order? It is possible for $AB$ to be the identity, with the dimensions you described.

Comment: I will attach the matrices above in the question

Comment: then the question says show that $B$ is an inverse to the left

Comment: but not from the right. Then it says this is why we will stick to square matrices in my abstract algebra class. Is the question a typo perhaps?

Comment: @K.Gibson The point to take away from this and theorems you will soon be studying and prove is that only square matrices have the ability to be both left and right handed inverses.  If a matrix is not square, it has the ability to be a left handed inverse while not being a right handed inverse and vice versa and in fact if it *is* a left handed inverse you can be certain that it is *not* a right handed inverse and vice versa in the event that the matrix is not square.

Comment: @K.Gibson Now... yes, there may have been a typo or you read the words incorrectly as to whether BA should have been the identity or whether it should have instead been AB.  If you find AB is the identity, then A will be the left-inverse of B while B is the right-inverse of A.  B *has* a left-inverse which is A, and so on... however you wish to arrange the words and meanings to get across the relationship between A and B.